# Pig: Group By, Average, and Order By

Tags: sorting, group-by, apache-pig, average

I am new to pig and I have a text file where each line contains a different record of information in the following format:

```
name, year, count, uniquecount
```

For example:

```
Zverkov winced_VERB 2004    8   8
Zverkov winced_VERB 2008    4   4
Zverkov winced_VERB 2009    1   1
zvlastni _ADV_  1913    1   1
zvlastni _ADV_  1928    2   2
zvlastni _ADV_  1929    3   2
```

I want to group all the records by their unique names, then for each unique name calculate count/uniquecount, and finally sort the output by this calculated value.

Here is what I have been trying:

```
bigrams = LOAD 'input/bigram/zv.gz' AS (bigram:chararray, year:int, count:float, books:float);
group_bigrams = GROUP bigrams BY bigram;
average_bigrams = FOREACH group_bigrams GENERATE group, SUM(bigrams.count) / SUM(bigrams.books) AS average;
sorted_bigrams = ORDER average_bigrams BY average;
```

Comment: Plz. share input test data and required output to better understand the use case.

Comment: Go ahead and try something, then put your code and problems here and we will be happy to help.

Comment: I added an update with the code I have been trying. Please let me know if you need additional information.

Comment: @MrFlom: Plz share input test data and expected output for the same.

Comment: @MuraliRao You can download the input data [here](http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=43275259334419717513). The expected output would be something like:
1. uniquename1, 50
2. uniquename2, 40
3. uniquename3, 35
etc

Comment: @MrFlom : The second value in the output is the average right ? The script added in the question, is it not giving the desired output ?

Comment: Yes, you should give the current output and explain why it doesn't suit you.

Comment: @MuraliRao Yes, the second value in the output is the average and yes, the script added in the question is not giving the desired output.

Comment: @MrFlom: For an input : Zverkov winced_VERB 2004 8 8;Zverkov winced_VERB 2008 4 4;Zverkov winced_VERB 2009 1 1;zvlastni _ADV_ 1913 1 1;zvlastni _ADV_ 1928 2 2;zvlastni _ADV_ 1929 3 2;  We will be getting the ouput : (Zverkov winced_VERB,1.0); (zvlastni _ADV_,1.2) (replace ; to \n in both input and output), if this is NOT the expected output, add the expected output to the question along with the input sample shared here.

Comment: @MrFlom : Sample Input has been added to the question. Plz. add the expected output for the sample input shared.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems my original code does produce the desired output with one minor change:

```
bigrams = LOAD 'input/bigram/zv.gz' AS (bigram:chararray, year:int, count:float, books:float);
group_bigrams = GROUP bigrams BY bigram;
average_bigrams = FOREACH group_bigrams GENERATE group, SUM(bigrams.count)/SUM(bigrams.books) AS average;
sorted_bigrams = ORDER average_bigrams BY average DESC, group ASC;
```